# SQL Daily, weekly, monthly backup

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, database-backups

I have daily backups set up for all databases. The servers tend to get full of backups after a while and I have to go through and periodically clean it up. I would like to retain the daily backups for 30 days, then retain one backup weekly for 6 months, and then retain one backup monthly for 12 months. How do i set this up in SQL or outside of SQL? The retention needs will also vary between databases. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what flavour of sql are you using

Comment: I'm using SQL 2008 R2.

Comment: you can set up an SQL Agent job to go through and delete back up sets that are older than 30 days.

Comment: SQL server agent is part of the issue. It will not run on one of the servers for some reason and on the server that it does run it, the cleanup segment does not work. I'm hoping to set up two new 2012 servers soon and deprecate these, but until then I am looking for a work around.

Comment: Is the Agent running on that server? If all fails you can use powershell and schedule it via windows scheduler that's an option.

Comment: OK thanks! I will try that.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create Three agent job FULLBACK_DAILY, FULLBACK_WEEKLY, FULLBACK_MONTHLY 
   Step 1 Take fullbackup for DB
   Step 2 Cleanup old backup using powershell.
2. Scheduled them daily, weekly and monthly

Question: The retention needs will also vary between databases.
You can do this in the fullbackup step.

Good luck

Comment: When I get the SQL Agent working again, I will try that. Thanks!